# Usar varios 'if - else' o 'switch' en un método

Tags: java, java-swing

He creado un método en Java que me permita "checkear" varios `JTextFields` , la idea es que un usuario introduzca sus datos personales ( nombre, apellido ,email , password etc)

y que este método me permita checkear si los `JTextfields` no son `NULL` , el formato del Email es el correcto y por ultimo que la password no sea `NULL`.

```
public boolean checkRegistrationData(ArrayList<JTextField> jTxts, JPasswordField pass, JTextField theEmail) {

    if (isJtextNotNull(jTxts) && isJPasswordNotNull(pass) && isValidEmailAddress(theEmail)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A confirmation Code has been sent to your Email adress");
        return true;

    } else if (isJtextNotNull(jTxts) && !isJPasswordNotNull(pass) && isValidEmailAddress(theEmail)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The password field is empty");
        return false;

    } else if (isJtextNotNull(jTxts) && isJPasswordNotNull(pass) && !isValidEmailAddress(theEmail)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The email address is not valid");
        return false;
    }

    else {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some data is empty");
        return false;
    }
}
```

el `ArrayList<JTextField> jTxts` es donde estan "guardados" la mayoria de JTextFields con los datos del usuario.

Hay alguna forma de mejorar este método ? seria mejor usar switch?

Comment: Además de las respuestas que te han dado, la instrucción *switch* siempre es más rápida que una serie de instrucciones *if-else* anidadas ya que las condiciones de los *if* se evalúan todas. Sin embargo el switch calcula el valor que se está evaluando y lo compara con las entradas del case, lo cual es mas rapido que evaluar todos los if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un patrón común ([Guard clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computer_science%29)/[Early exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit)) consiste en comprobar al principio del método que los argumentos son válidos, saliendo del método si no es así. De esta forma, se separa el verdadero objetivo del método, de las comprobaciones previas. Con ese patrón, el método quedaría como sigue:

```
public boolean checkRegistrationData(ArrayList<JTextField> jTxts, JPasswordField pass, JTextField theEmail) {

    if (!isJtextNotNull(jTxts)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some data is empty");
        return false;
    }

    if (!isJPasswordNotNull(pass)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The password field is empty");
        return false;
    }

    if (!isValidEmailAddress(theEmail)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The email address is not valid");
        return false;
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A confirmation Code has been sent to your Email adress");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Para evitar mostrar un mensaje por cada tipo de error, lo cual podría ser engorroso para el usuario, puedes agrupar *todos* los errores con la ayuda de una lista. Esto es:

#### ✍ Código

```
public boolean checkRegistrationData(ArrayList<JTextField> jTxts, JPasswordField pass, JTextField theEmail) {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!isJtextNotNull(jTxts)) {
        errors.add("Some data is empty");
    }
    if (!isJPasswordNotNull(pass)) {
        errors.add("The password field is empty");
    }
    if (!isValidEmailAddress(theEmail)) {
        errors.add("The email address is not valid");
    }
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A confirmation Code has been sent to your Email adress");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.join("\n", errors));
    }
    return errors.isEmpty();
}
```

#### ✍ Salida

[image: captura]

De esta manera, muestras todos los errores que existan en los datos introducidos y el usuario tiene oportunidad de corregir *todos* a la vez.

Comment: Muy útil , gracias!

Answer (score 1):

`switch` te sería útil para evaluar los distintos resultados de una misma expresión. Siempre es más eficiente un switch que una concatenación de if,elseif...else. Pero en tu caso evalúas 4 expresiones distintas:

> 1. isJtextNotNull(jTxts) && isJPasswordNotNull(pass) &&
>      isValidEmailAddress(theEmail)
> 2. isJtextNotNull(jTxts) && !isJPasswordNotNull(pass) &&
>      isValidEmailAddress(theEmail)
> 3. isJtextNotNull(jTxts) && isJPasswordNotNull(pass) &&
>      !isValidEmailAddress(theEmail)
> 4. Si ninguna expresión es verdadera

No le veo mucho sentido utilizar switch en este caso salvo que uses una variable extra, por ejemplo *estado_del_formulario*, y que su valor se corresponda con cada uno de los posibles estados del formulario.